# How to remove space between cardview and button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview, cardview

I want to remove extra space inside the `CardView` so the buttons does not have a white border as shown in the picture . This image was captured from my tablet but the Layout looks well in 5 Inch Mobile devices

[image: ![https://ibb.co/yYvGkS3]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp">

                <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                    style="@style/RippleStyleWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/twitter_button"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_twitter"
                        android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Twitter"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp">

                <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                    style="@style/RippleStyleWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/facebook_button"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                        android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Facebook"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for the CardViews and the buttons. I didn't paste the whole layout code because I don't think it has effect on my problem and by the way I tried changing margins of the buttons but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Just don't put the buttons inside an unnecessary cardview...

Comment: yes i used marginbottom of 10dp for each edittext @Ashish

Comment: It gives the buttons a 3d effect so it is necessary I think @Julio

Comment: The 3D effect you want can be achieved by giving a value to the elevation property of the buttons.

Comment: remove android:paddingStart="10dp" from the Button.

Comment: I had to read this twice. There's remove space between cardview and button then remove space because don't want white borders of buttons. Don't know which.

Comment: Removing the android:paddingStart="10dp" doesn't solve the problem @Cergo

Comment: It is the same @CmosBaterry the space between the cardview and the button makes the button look as it have a white border

Comment: Ok, did you try the button directly without om.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout ?

Comment: Yes and I got the same result @Cergo .. com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout just gives the button style when clicked

Comment: @GeekyOmar try to add card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
or app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"

Answer (score 0):

From library documentation it is nowhere mentioned that you need to use can completely remove the cardview as it seems unnecessary. You can remove your cardview and enclose your button directly in `MaterialRippleLayout` to achieve your ripple effect. Check library description here https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple.

Comment: The cardview is necessary to contain the material ripple layout effect

Comment: removing the app:cardCornerRadius="20dp" didn't solve the problem

Comment: you have also set `android:paddingStart="10dp"` try removing that also.

Comment: also in library it is no where mentioned that you need to use cardview. try directly using materialripplelayout with button inside it.

Comment: Using the material ripple layout directly makes the effect of it fill the whole space inside the linear layout

Comment: use layout width and height properly.

Comment: any suggestions ? @Karan Mer